# Is the $\pi$-system generated by a topology the topology itself?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I was studying the introduction for my probability course, and came to the definition of a $\pi$-system.

> Let $C \subset \mathcal{\Omega}$. $C$ is a $\pi$-system if $\forall A, B \in C \implies A \cap B \in C$.

But from the definition of a topology, does that mean that if $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology, then $\pi(\mathcal{T}) = \mathcal{T}$?

Where $\pi(\mathcal{T})$ is the $\pi$-system generated by $\mathcal{T}$.

If this is the case, I would ask a less rigorous question: Is the $\pi$-system the probability theory equivalent of a topology?

EDIT: The definition I am using for the $\pi$-system generated by $\mathcal{T}$ is the smallest $\pi$-system that contains the topology $\mathcal{T}$

Comment: What do you mean with $\pi$-system generated by a topology? The smallest $\pi$-system containing that topology? Also, the probability theory equivalent of a topology is most likely a $\sigma$-algebra, which is stronger than $\pi$-system.

Comment: Yes, the smallest $\pi$-system containing the topology, I'll add it to the question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the topology in the question with $\mathcal{T}$. We want to prove that

$$\pi(\mathcal{T}) = \mathcal{T}$$

Clearly, we have $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \pi( \mathcal{T}).$

The other inclusion $\pi (\mathcal{T}) \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ is immediate, since $\mathcal{T}$ is a $\pi$-system that contains $\mathcal{T}$, and we then use minimality.

Comment: Hi thanks again for you kind support during the suspension time. If you are interested I've raised a related discussion [HERE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29254/505767). Cheers

Comment: @gimusi  Glad you are back. Hope you aren't fighting anything that is unfightable.

Comment: No fighting, I'm just trying to discuss how to deal with different point of view in a respectful way. Bye